# How did the code execution get inside this 'if' statement?

Tags: c#, string, http, url, startswith

Look at the following code:

```
    public static string GetCleanURL(string baseURL, string url)
    {
        string cleanUrl = url.ToLower();
        if (cleanUrl.StartsWith("http://"))
        {//It already starts with http://  It is already in the correct form return it.
            return cleanUrl;
        }
```

The 'url' value passed in is "123.123.123.123:1234/myurl/withstuff.xml".  In the 'if' statement, the value for 'cleanUrl' is "123.123.123.123:1234/myurl/withstuff.xml".  But for some reason, the code execution goes inside of the if block and 'return cleanUrl;' gets executed.

Here is a screenshot of the current value for 'cleanUrl':

[image]

When I plug `cleanUrl.StartsWith("http://")` into the 'Immediate Window' of my debugger, it returns false.  Which is what I would expect.  However, the execution is somehow going into the if block as though it had returned true.

Can anybody please explain how this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED !!!**

I appreciate those of you who helped me out on this one.

**I needed to Clean and Rebuild my project and Close and Reopen Visual Studio 2013 about 4 times** before the code base and debug stuff was actually in sync.  It now appears to be working correctly.

Not sure why it ever got that way, or why I needed to do Clean/Rebuild several times before things synced up.  But it is working now.

So, friends, if ever you find your code is just acting crazy and not doing what it should do.  Just realize that anybody in their right mind would never become a programmer.  Then do a clean / rebuild a few times and pray that the oddity goes away never to return.

Thanks for all your help on this one.

**I LOVE fighting with the development tools...**

Comment: I wouldn't call this "solved"... you don't know why it happened or what fixed it, you just turned it off and on again and off and on and off and on and off and on again.

My guess is that you had optimizations turned on, so the line highlighted by the debugger was not accurate. The gold standard for whether the body ran is to print something in that body and see that it was printed.

Comment: I had been doing unit testing and my guess is that I updated the code and then clicked on the test harness and had it run the test.  My assumption is that Visual Studio didn't completely update the debug info to match the source code.  After a couple cleans and rebuilds, it seems to be fine.  The code is pretty strait forward so I don't know what else it could be.  If you have any other ideas, please let me know.  I was pretty baffled by the whole thing.  I'm just glad its not doing it anymore..

Answer (score 1):

No, `StartWith` isn't buggy, and works as expected.

Try the minimal code below. Reduce your code to the minimum amount to reprouce the problem. Does this happen everytime?
Does it happen with more than one candidate string? Or only that string?

Something else is going on sorry, the following writes `Doesn't start`

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string cleanUrl = "123.123.123.123:1234/SomeFile.xml";
        if (cleanUrl.StartsWith("http://"))
            Console.WriteLine("Starts");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Doesn't start");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: A person comes to you and says he has a problem, and instead of solving it you tell him that he doesn't have a problem.

Comment: Actually he says that the problem perceived is not the actual problem.

Comment: This answers seems unnecessary since anyone can see that "123.12..." does not start with "http://" and that the problem is actually elsewhere.

Comment: That's okay, @Magnus.  Soon, he'll find the problem and the question will either be deleted or downvoted to oblivion.

Comment: @YoryeNathan: Eh, I believe I've answered the question as asked "Is there a bug in `StartsWith` . . .". Which, is the correct answer. Now, helping the asker determine the actual problem is another matter, and potentially another SO question.

Comment: @TaW Obvious and still very unhelpful.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier Yeah, lets also stop pointing out to people that they should use parametrized queries instead of concatenating strings when the question is about something else.

Comment: @YoryeNathan: Aren't you in a fine mood today! Beautiful day! Lets spread the love of the day today! Good will to all and to all good cheer! Hurra!